# How to keep only those rows which are unique in a tab-delimited file in unix

Tags: linux

Here, two rows are considered redundant if second value is same. 
Is there any unix/linux command that can achieve the following.

```
1   aa
2   aa
1   ss
3   dd
4   dd
```

Result

```
1   aa
1   ss
3   dd
```

I generally use the following command but it does not achieve what I want here.

```
sort -k2 /Users/fahim/Desktop/delnow2.csv | uniq
```

Edit:

My file had roughly 25 million lines:
Time when using the solution suggested by @Steve : 33 seconds.

```
$date; awk -F '\t' '!a[$2]++' myfile.txt  > outfile.txt; date
Wed Nov 27 18:00:16 EST 2013
Wed Nov 27 18:00:49 EST 2013
```

The sort and unique is taking too much time. I quit after waiting for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
awk -F "\t" '!a[$2]++' file
```

Results:

```
1   aa
1   ss
3   dd
```

Comment: Your solution is really fast than what I was planning to adopt. Thanks

Comment: pl see the time comparison

Comment: @user1140126: Cool. You could use `time` instead of `date`: `time awk ...`

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want a unique sorted file by the second field.
You need to add -u to sort to achieve this.

```
sort -u -k2 /Users/fahim/Desktop/delnow2.csv
```